# INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Tried to run my test cases on eclipse through the selenium webdriver. It only works on Firefox driver and Chrome driver but it doesn't work on IE driver. The error in the console reads as:

INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Nov 18, 2013 4:26:01 PM 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute

INFO: Retrying request

Nov 18, 2013 4:26:10 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute

INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset 
Nov 18, 2013 4:26:10 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute INFO: Retrying request –

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class MaggiesSanityTesting {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp2() throws Exception {
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://maggies.latestcreativework.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("HOW MAGGIE’S CAN HELP")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.sibling")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("OUR CENTRES")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("HOW YOU CAN HELP")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("ABOUT MAGGIE’S")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"Maggie's Logo\"]")).click();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
}

private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
        } else {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
        return alertText;
    } finally {
        acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Edit [your existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051667/ie-webdriver-isnt-running-my-code), rather than asking a new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache http client org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237486/apache-http-client-org-apache-http-nohttpresponseexception-the-target-server-fa)