# How to solve NoHttpresponseException for Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate in order to invoke external REST APIs from my Spring boot application as follows:

```
  @Bean("myRestTemplate")
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

    return builder
        .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectionTimeout))
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeout))
        .build();
  }
```

Here, while calling external API, getting following error intermittently:

```
exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: xyz.com:443 failed to respond
```

I am using this `RestTemplate from spring-web 5.2.9.RELEASE.`

In this context, I have gone through the following posts:

1. [Apache HttpClient Interim Error: NoHttpResponseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558791/apache-httpclient-interim-error-nohttpresponseexception). But it deals with HttpClient mostly.
2. [Rest Template org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379786/rest-template-org-apache-http-nohttpresponseexcep), here also I could not figure out how to solve this for `RestTemplate`

Could anyone please help here?

Comment: Are you sure you should be looking at your client and not whatever it is you're talking to.  Could it be that the remote side really "failed to respond"?

Comment: This seems like a server side issue. Try getting the response from the server using CURL with verbose.