# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Tags: android

I am using the following code to post Image to server,but  it is giving error below

**org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond**

I did not understand whether the issue is from Server side or from my Code side.

can anyone please help me in solving this issue?

code:

```
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... arg0) {

            CustomMultiPartEntity multipartContent = new CustomMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });
            try {
                for (int i = Constants.IMAGE_SELECTION; i < al_image_paths
                        .size(); i++) {
                    count = i + 1;
                    progressDialog.setProgress(0);

                    // String url=DataUrl.hostId+"/addpost/postImageOrVideo?";
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(image_upload);

                    Log.e("strImagePath.... before uploading",
                            al_image_paths.get(i));

                    multipartContent.addPart("image", new FileBody(new File(
                            al_image_paths.get(i))));
                    multipartContent.addPart("sellleadid",
                            new StringBody(pref.getString("sellerID", "")));
                    multipartContent.addPart("action", new StringBody(
                            "Send Used Car Images"));
                    multipartContent.addPart("app_id", new StringBody(Constants.DEVICE_ID));

                    totalSize = multipartContent.getContentLength();

                    httpPost.setEntity(multipartContent);

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                            localContext);
                    String serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response
                            .getEntity());
                    Log.e("serverResponse image", "<> " + serverResponse);

                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(serverResponse);

                    if (object.getString("status").equals("200")) {
                        selectedImageIds.add(object.getString("imageid"));
                        selectedUrls.add(object.getString("url"));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }`enter code here`
```

Comment: What row does throw NoHttpResponseException?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your manifest file.

Also check - [Apache HttpClient Interim Error: NoHttpResponseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558791/apache-httpclient-interim-error-nohttpresponseexception).

**EDIT:**

```
java.io.IOException
 +- org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException
```

> In some circumstances, usually when under heavy load, the web server
>   may be able to receive requests but unable to process them. A lack of
>   sufficient resources like worker threads is a good example. This may
>   cause the server to drop the connection to the client without giving
>   any response. HttpClient throws NoHttpResponseException when it
>   encounters such a condition. In most cases it is safe to retry a
>   method that failed with NoHttpResponseException.

**SOURCE:** http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html

Comment: I have Internet permission

Comment: Check my update. So you have the idea that why and where the exception could be.

Comment: i use `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost`, how to custom exception handler? Thanks.