# I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond

Tags: java, performance

I am getting the below logs from our application (Log level:INFO)

> I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond

Can someone help me to figure out why these errors are coming?

I googled but could not find any detailed response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have tweaked your post.  I think you need to provide more details about your application.  Ideally, you would post a cut down version that still produces a problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As this is a _single_ log line, it is more readable as a quote than a code block. (Doesn't need horizontal scrolling, but won't preserve line breaks.) I've also fixed a small typo and removed an unnecessary closing.

Comment: The search feature is your friend: [Apache HttpClient Interim Error: NoHttpResponseException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558791/apache-httpclient-interim-error-nohttpresponseexception)