# why NoHttpResponseException occues while using sdn4

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

we use sdn4 to access neo4j,but sometimes this exception occurs. what's the reason? neo4j's version 2.2.5。what config we can config to avoid this exception?

```
  at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.DefaultRequest.execute(DefaultRequest.java:105) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.4-20151201.162656-1.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.SessionRequestHandler.execute(SessionRequestHandler.java:99) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.4-20151201.162656-1.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.SessionRequestHandler.execute(SessionRequestHandler.java:64) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.4-20151201.162656-1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery$1.apply(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:65) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery$1.apply(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate.doInTransaction(TransactionsDelegate.java:54) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.4-20151201.162656-1.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:422) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.4-20151201.162656-1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.mapToConcreteType(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(QueryResultGraphRepositoryQuery.java:52) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:50) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:454) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:432) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 10.171.23.230:7475 failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.DefaultRequest.execute(DefaultRequest.java:80) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.4-20151201.162656-1.jar:na]
... 56 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the server has closed the connection due to a long period of inactivity. The [Apache HttpClient documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e659) states this:

> 2.6. Connection keep alive strategy The HTTP specification does not specify how long a persistent connection may be and should be kept
>   alive. Some HTTP servers use a non-standard Keep-Alive header to
>   communicate to the client the period of time in seconds they intend to
>   keep the connection alive on the server side. HttpClient makes use of
>   this information if available. If the Keep-Alive header is not present
>   in the response, HttpClient assumes the connection can be kept alive
>   indefinitely. However, many HTTP servers in general use are configured
>   to drop persistent connections after a certain period of inactivity in
>   order to conserve system resources, quite often without informing the
>   client

Normally, re-using a stale connection would be detected, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558791/apache-httpclient-interim-error-nohttpresponseexception) suggests that under some circumstances a write request on a stale connection can appear to succeed. In this case the lack of a valid response will give rise to the `org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException`

SDN does not currently have any mechanism to mitigate against this problem, and I'm not aware of any settings in *neo4j-server.properties* to prevent this behaviour on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The latest snapshot version of the OGM, 1.1.5-SNAPSHOT has a request retry strategy enabled in the event that a NoHttpResponseException is thrown: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm

The retry strategy is configured to attempt the request 3 more times after the initial failure, with a delay of 2 seconds between each attempt.

The rationale for this strategy is based on the Apache HttpClient documentation which states the following:

> In some circumstances, usually when under heavy load, the web server may be able to receive requests but unable to process them. A lack of sufficient resources like worker threads is a good example. This may cause the server to drop the connection to the client without giving any response. HttpClient throws NoHttpResponseException when it encounters such a condition. In most cases it is safe to retry a method that failed with NoHttpResponseException.
>   http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html

The 1.1.5-SNAPSHOT version of the OGM is compatible with SDN 4.0.

**OGM users**

If you're using the OGM "standalone", you'll need to add this dependency to your pom:

```
<repository>
    <id>neo4j-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

**SDN users**

The required dependency should already be included in the latest Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT build. You'll need the following repository in your pom to use the snapshot build of SDN 4.0

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
    <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```