# HTTP 502 "Bad Gateway" / writev() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: http, nginx, jetty, dropwizard

[image]

We have the configuration above, where the server handles up to 100 concurrent requests, a few of them are rather large: up to 3-4MB payload, at a single request (not using multi-part etc.)

This works fine, but once in a while we get an error from the nginx:
`HTTP 502 "Bad Gateway"`

In the access log we see

`writev() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending request to upstream`

or: `recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream`

There is no error from on the Java (Jetty/Dropwizard) server.

We assume this is due to Jetty closing the connection a bit too soon, maybe sending a response even before receiving data completed?!

We tried to increase the buffer size on nginx:

`client_max_body_size 24M;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;`

and lowered the keep_alive idle timeout (60 -> 25 sec) to avoid a case where the jetty closes it a bit sooner (30 sec timeout):
  `proxy_http_version  1.1;
  proxy_set_header    Connection "";
  keepalive_timeout   25;`

This didn't make a change.
Headers shouldn't be large. and 99.9% of the requests work as expected (all requests are similar).

A weird thing is that after upgrading Dropwizard (1.2.2 -> 1.3.5) and Jetty (9.4.7 -> 9.4.11) the errors happen x20 more often.

I wonder what should be the next steps of investigation?
What could have happened / what are the pitfalls we could try workaround?

Comment: possibly relevant reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600762/3834036

Comment: Possibly relevant resource: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2791