# I received an error org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException: server failed to respond when i call API via quotaguard proxy in SpringBoot 3

Tags: spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, java-17, spring-boot-3, apache-httpclient-5.x

We are using QuotaGuard proxy to connect with external API.
Recently we did Spring Boot version update.
Technical configuration of our application.
**Before Spring Boot version update.**
Java 8
Spring Boot 2.7
Htttclient 4.5
**After Spring Boot version update.**
Java 17
Spring Boot 3.0
Htttclient5 5.2.1
However after migration we cannot connect to the API. We get the following error message.

```
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1 org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "[https://test.com/postInfo]": [test.com:443]  failed to respond
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:888)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:868)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:512)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at jp.co.demo.service.WinnerExportServiceImpl$3.doWithRetry(WinnerExportServiceImpl.java:381)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at jp.co.demo.service.WinnerExportServiceImpl$3.doWithRetry(WinnerExportServiceImpl.java:376)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:179)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at jp.co.demo.service.WinnerExportServiceImpl.execute(WinnerExportServiceImpl.java:376)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$toSupplier$0(FutureUtils.java:74)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1 Caused by: org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException: [test.com:443] failed to respond
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpResponseParser.createConnectionClosedException(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:87)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:243)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:53)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:298)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:175)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.io.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:218)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionEndpoint.execute(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:712)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.execute(InternalExecRuntime.java:216)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.createTunnelToTarget(ConnectExec.java:233)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:151)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:93)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:862)
Nov 29 02:57:08  app/web.1  ... 20 more
```

Here are the sample code we are using,

```
URL proxy;
proxy = new URL(proxyUrl);
String userInfo = proxy.getUserInfo();
String user = userInfo.substring(0, userInfo.indexOf(':'));
String password = userInfo.substring(userInfo.indexOf(':') + 1);

final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password.toCharArray());
((BasicCredentialsProvider) credsProvider).setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxy.getHost(), proxy.getPort()), credentials);

HttpHost p = new HttpHost(proxy.getHost(), proxy.getPort());
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setProxy(p).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
ResponseEntity<ResponseData> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(APIURL, req, ResponseData.class);
ResponseData responseBody = response.getBody();
```

However if we request API using quotaguard proxy via CURL on the command line, it passes successfully.
Also if we request API using Postman, it passes successfully.
Did anyone faced problem to connect API using proxyserver recently after updating SpringBoot 3.0 and Java 17 version?
Can anyone give any guideline how to approach or fix this problem? We have tried several method and example code none of them worked.

Comment: How to test this?

Comment: @AnishB. 
I am sorry but we do not have control over API. API is manager by 3rd party. Only way to test is call API from secured environment within company.

Comment: I was trying to signup with quotaguard. But they are telling to add credit card to start the trial version. Is there any way to test on the local with someother proxy server?

Comment: I can fix the issue but I was looking for some way to reproduce this on my local.

Comment: Yes, I think Quotaguard charges for trial also. If you have any concept or idea how to fix it, you can post it as answer. Then we can test your concept in our environment and let you know.

Comment: have you tried upgrading to httpclient5?

Comment: Yes, I did. Previously i used Httpclient 4.5. Currently using Httpclient5 5.2.1 version.

Comment: I'm seeing other posts indicating that this could be due to connection reuse or timeouts. Have you tried setting the connection reuse strategy to not reuse connections?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558791/apache-httpclient-interim-error-nohttpresponseexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far i found two solutions. Both are working for my scenario.

Solution 1: Telling the system to not keep alive the connection by setting setConnectionReuseStrategy.

```
final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = Httpclients.custom()
        .setProxy(p)
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new ConnectionReuseStrategy(){
            @Override
            public boolean keepAlive(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context){
                return false;
            }
        }).build();
```

Solution 2: Implementing CustomRetryStrategy which implements RetryStrategy. Then Set CustomRetryStrategy in setRetryStrategy.

```
final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = Httpclients.custom()
        .setProxy(p)
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .setRetryStrategy(new CustomRetryStrategy())
        }).build();     
        
private static class CustomRetryStrategy implements RetryStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean retryRequest(HttpRequest request, IOException exception, int execCount, HttpContext context) {
        //Set execCount according to business requirement.
        return execCount <= 3 ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retryRequest(HttpResponse response, int execCount, HttpContext context) {
        //Set execCount according to business requirement.
        return execCount <= 3 ;
    }


    @Override
    public TimeValue getRetryInterval(HttpResponse response, int execCount, RetryExec exec) {
        return TimeValue.ofSeconds(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: How solution 2 works? Will it retry for 2 more times and close the connection?

Comment: A better solution would be figuring out what a stale connection ended up in the connection pool in the first place and configure the pool to validate or proactively evict such connections

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stacktrace, it seems that it cannot connect to the endpoint.

I've seen you're using proxy too.

Maybe there's some api changes that need rewriting since going from httpclient4 to httpclient5 (I've already spotted that some methods were kept from v4 to v5 but were no-op in v5)

The [setProxy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html#setProxy-org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpHost-) seems deprecated also.

Try setting the proxy this way :

```java
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 8090);
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
  .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
  .build();
```

You can also look at full example with auth info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-advanced-config#configuring-the-http-client-to-authorize-via-proxy)

If not working (as suggested in the comment), and not all your call to the API are failing, the real root-cause should be that your endpoint or proxy is ending the connection without noticing your client it has, so the RestTemplate is using a already closed connection (as suggested by the stacktrace location (`createConnectionClosedException`) :

> Subclasses must override this method to generate an appropriate exception in case of unexpected connection termination by the peer endpoint.

Maybe there's some changes in the default properties of `HttpClient` as pointed out in their [migration guide](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/migration-guide/migration-to-classic.html)

> Major differences are related to connection management configuration, SSL/TLS and timeout settings when building HttpClient instances.

They also suggest the following :

> Set finite socket and connect timeouts.
>
> Set finite connection total time to live (TTL).

Since the connection is closed by the remote endpoint, setting a low TTL for connections could allow the connection manager to close connections that are not more usable.

Another option would be to call the following methods while creating your HttpClient

> Makes this instance of HttpClient proactively evict expired connections from the connection pool using a background thread : `org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder.evictExpiredConnections()`
>
> Makes this instance of HttpClient proactively evict idle connections from the connection pool using a background thread : `org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder.evictIdleConnections(TimeValue)`

Doing so, your ConnectionManager will check if connection are expired or idle for too long and close them proactively, so you won't be using them when doing another call to the API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But we have already modified the code using CloseableHttpClient with setting setRoutePlanner and it did not worked.

Comment: It was one point of the migration process :), will update my answer according your response and deeper analysis of the problem